# Topology on the set of closed subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Tags: general-topology

I have applications $\mathbb{R}\ni t\mapsto C(t)$ where $C(t)$ is a closed subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

I want to say that these applications are continuous/discontinuous. 
What topology can we put on the set of closed subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: Whatever one comes up with, it cannot be given by an obvious metric since $X:=\operatorname{Gr}(\exp) = \exp(\mathbb R)$, the graph of $\exp$ and $Y:= \{(x,0) \mid x \in \mathbb R\}$ are closed in $\mathbb R^2$ and $d(X,Y) = \inf\{d(x,y) \mid x \in X, y \in Y\} = 0$.

Comment: @kahen You are right. Your example make me think that we can try something like $\max \{ d(x,Y),d(y,X) \mid x\in X, y\in Y\}$.

Comment: I have just read that this metric has a name: this is the Hausdorff distance. It induced a strictly finer topology then the Fell topology. My ref is chapter 12 of "Stochastic and Integral geometry" of R. Scneider and W. Weil. But it is defined only for non empty compact closed subsets of $R^n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For instance, you can take Fell topology (see, for instance, a paper
“[Fell topology on hyperspaces of locally compact spaces](http://www.franko.lviv.ua/faculty/mechmat/Departments/Topology/banpap/Fell.pdf)”
by my scientific consultant [Taras Banakh](http://www.franko.lviv.ua/faculty/mechmat/Departments/Topology/bancv.html)  and his student [Rostyslav Voytsitskyy](http://genealogy.math.ndsu.nodak.edu/id.php?id=129015)).

Comment: It is nice to note that we can define the Hausdorff metric with an explicit formula and that gives us a finer topology. c.f. comments below the question.